# About JavaScript function parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I'm newer in JavaScript.So maybe my question will seem naive.

My JavaScript Code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 var defaultText = "Enter your text here";
 function WaterMark(txt, evt) 
 {
    if(txt.value.length == 0 && evt.type == "blur")
    {
        txt.style.color = "gray";
        txt.value = defaultText;
    }
    if(txt.value == defaultText && evt.type == "focus") 
    {
        txt.style.color = "black";
        txt.value=""; 
    }
 }
```

ASP declaration:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text = "Enter your text here
ForeColor = "Gray" 
onblur = "WaterMark(this, event);" 
onfocus = "WaterMark(this, event);">
```

My quetstion is about parameters of this two events:

```
  onblur = "WaterMark(this, event);" 
  onfocus = "WaterMark(this, event);"
```

If i understood correctly word **this** means the current control.

And what is meaning of the second parameter, **event** ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the event arguments, or `EventArgs`.  They can contain a set of variables that existed at the time the event was created, to provide additional context to the event handler.  It's basically a way to pass information into your event handler.

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/11/07/ASPNET-AJAX-Create-a-JavaScript-Component-with-Events.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its the event object which contains information about the currently fired event. In IE, the event object is in the global "window" object. Mozilla/Chrome pass it as a parameter to the event handler

In the first line of your event handler, you can do this to support all browsers

```
event = event || window.event
```

If the "event" parameter is not present take it up from the window object. It will not be present in IE.